# Query postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am doing the function of booking a hotel, when I get the rooms available by date by following

```
SELECT * 
FROM oder 
WHERE
    startDate >= '2020-12-26 06:53:18.114+00' AND 
    endDate <= '2020-12-30 06:53:18.114+00'
```

but it works when i enter the exact start and end date stored in the database, i want when i enter the start and end date time can be within the period stored in the database, I can also get the room that was booked.

example: I choose the startDate = 2020-12-27 and the endDate=2020-12-28is within the period of 2020-12-26 to 2020-12-30, I want the result to return like the above query

```
SELECT * 
FROM oder 
WHERE
    startDate >= '2020-12-26 06:53:18.114+00' AND
    endDate <= '2020-12-28 06:53:18.114+00'
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output. Incl. some data which wouldn't fit the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might be interested in a range datatype, [tsrange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) in this case. When using a range, you can also create a [constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT) to avoid double bookings.

The various [range functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) will help you to find the records you're looking for.

edit: When using a range and looking for records that overlap, this query might do the job:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    oder 
WHERE
    tsrange_field && tsrange ( '2020-12-26 06:53:18.114+00', '2020-12-28 06:53:18.114+00', '[]' );
```

Assumption: Field tsrange_field will be the field where you store your timestamp ranges.

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, You need the rooms booked for the period that is given by you as an input.

You can use the `OR` condition and `BETWEEN` as follows:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM oder 
 WHERE startDate between '2020-12-26 06:53:18.114+00' AND '2020-12-30 06:53:18.114+00'
    or endDate between '2020-12-26 06:53:18.114+00' AND '2020-12-30 06:53:18.114+00'
```